# Пустой цикл в версии Release

Tags: c++, циклы

Использую пустой цикл

```
while (botsReady < botsCount);
```

что бы просто не выполнять последующий код, пока все боты не будут готовы.
На сборке Debug всё работает прекрасно, однако, когда я переключился на Release, то почему-то этот цикл.. сломался?

Он просто не работает, будто я написал вместо него `system("pause");`, но когда я пишу в тело цикла какой-нибудь код, типа

```
while (botsReady < botsCount) {
        cout << "q";
    }
```

то цикл внезапно начинает работать как и задумано, но если я напишу

```
while (botsReady < botsCount) {
    continue;
}
```

То снова ничего не работает.

Что это за приколы такие, и есть ли этому разумное объяснение? Использую MSVS17.

Comment: Потому что оптимизация. Делайте хоть что нибудь, хотя бы usleep. Либо убирайте оптимизацию. В коде без оптимизации "работать" будет всё.

Comment: @test123 а есть какой-то другой способ ожидания условия, как в моём примере?

Comment: while (botsReady < botsCount) Sleep(1);

Comment: Во-первых, объявите переменные как `volatile`, во-вторых, это крайне паршивый, жрущий процессор впустую способ. Не думали применить семафоры?

Answer (score 6):

Согласно стандарту C++ любой цикл без видимых побочных эффектов обязан завершаться, в противном случае поведение неопределено. А неопределенное поведение (Undefined behavior, UB) - это такая штука, при которой разрешено происходить чему угодно - даже бесконечный цикл может выполниться за конечное время.

Ваш пустой цикл как раз и попадает под UB, из-за чего оптимизатор его просто выкидывает.

Для того, чтобы этого не происходило, надо переменную `botsReady` объявить как `volatile` - это одновременно даст видимые побочные эффекты циклу (чтение volatile-переменной - тоже побочный эффект), и запретит компилятору оптимизировать чтение этой переменной.

---

Но ваш код все равно неправильный, причем фатально неправильный. Нельзя создавать несколько потоков которые используют общие переменные без синхронизации. И еще нельзя ждать как это делаете вы - в активном ожидании. Вы понимаете, что пока вы в одном потоке греете процессор своим циклом - в другом потоке не может выполняться код вашего бота, потому что процессор занят?

Правильным решением будет использовать примитив синхронизации ["барьер"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier):

```
std::experimental::barrier ready_barrier = { botsCount + 1 };

// в потоке бота

ready_barrier.arrive_and_drop();

// в основном потоке

ready_barrier.arrive_and_wait();
```

Кроме того, любой доступ к общим для разных потоков данным должен происходить под блокировкой.

Comment: Следовало бы добавить, что просто объявить переменную как `volatile` все равно не позволяет использовать ее из разных потоков без синхронизации. Хотя в VS имеется нестандартное расширение на этот счет.